# Python findall, regex

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have this text:

```
  u'times_viewed': 12268,
  u'url': u'/photo/79169307/30-seconds-light',
  u'user': {u'affection': 63962,
```

How can I just get out this string: `"/photo/79169307/30-seconds-light"`?

I am trying with regex and `findall`:

```
list = re.findall(‘u‘url‘: u‘/photo/"([^"]*)"‘, text)
```

but it won't go.

Comment: Did you try to read your string as json?

Comment: How did you try? Show us your regex.

Comment: That looks like output from a python data structure. If it is, maybe try: `object_name['url']` instead of printing it out? If not, then could you post the relevant portion of your failing code?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a name. it is [a builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Comment: Are you actually use accents instead of quotes/apostrophes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by "it won't go," you mean that you get a syntax error, which you should. Here:

```
list=re.findall(‘u‘url‘: u‘/photo/"([^"]*)"‘,text)
```

you're using `"` when you mean `'`. This is causing a syntax error because `"` closes the string you're trying to pass `re.findall`. Try:

```
list_ = re.findall("u'url': u'/photo/([^']*)'", text)
```

Additionally, this isn't going to grab the text after `photo`, so you'll need to add more parens:

```
list_ = re.findall("u'url': u'(/photo/([^']*))'", text)
```

and now `list_.group(1)` should hold your string.

On top of that, it looks like you're dealing with JSON. A better approach might be:

```
import json
json.loads(text)
list_ = text['url']
```

Comment: For your information: the regexes need to be closed with a quote charachter: `re.findall("u'url': u'/photo/([^']*)'", text)` and `"u'url': u'(/photo/([^']*))'"`

Comment: @xZise I think I fixed all of the typos. Let me know if there's anything else I missed.